# How can one find Reparse Points in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup, reparse-points

My backup keeps failing with error code 0x81000037 and [Microsoft's KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455) says that I have reparse points somewhere that are causing this.  How can I find them in a large group of files and folders?

Comment: I noticed alot of the junctions are in the C:\Users\Users\<Username>\AppData folders, and that I got alot of error loggings about those folders.  

So I'm going to try and remove those from the backup.  

Geez Microsoft you'd think you could give us a list of the bad junctions at least.

Comment: (in the error message...)

Comment: Note that generally you **don't need** to remove *all* reparse points, but only those of type "mounted volume", and only if they are at least partially including stuff in one of your "Libraries". See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/298019/what-can-i-do-about-windows-7-backup-error-0x81000037-apparently-caused-by-repar/339858#339858) for my detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dir *directory* /AD /S | find "<JUNCTION>"`
To save to a file:

```
dir *directory* /AD /S | find "<JUNCTION>" > *filename*.txt
```

On Windows 7 (not sure about Vista), you can also use:

```
dir /AL /S
```

to search for Reparse Points. This should be a lot faster than going through the whole directory contents then piping it to `find`.

Comment: Okay well that found them.  But there's soo soo many of them!