# What can I do about Windows 7 Backup error 0x81000037, apparently caused by reparse points?

Tags: windows-7, backup, ntfs, junction, reparse-points

I've been getting this error:

> 0x81000037: Windows Backup failed while trying to read from the shadow copy on one of the volumes being backed up

trying to take a Windows backup of my workstation (Windows 7 Professional x64)

The MS Knowledge Base article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455 provides an explanation and instructions on how to locate the reparse points that are causing the problem. Running this against my C: drive produces a rather extensive list...

```
Volume in drive C is Boot SSD
Volume Serial Number is 9066-FF1C

Directory of C:\

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core

2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-add.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-annotate.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-apply.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-archive.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-bisect--helper.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-blame.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-branch.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-bundle.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-cat-file.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-check-attr.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-check-ref-format.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-checkout-index.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-checkout.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-cherry-pick.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-cherry.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-clean.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-clone.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-commit-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-commit.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-config.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-count-objects.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-describe.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-diff-files.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-diff-index.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-diff-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-diff.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fast-export.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fetch-pack.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fetch.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fmt-merge-msg.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-for-each-ref.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-format-patch.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fsck-objects.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-fsck.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-gc.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-get-tar-commit-id.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-grep.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-hash-object.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-help.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-index-pack.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-init-db.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-init.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-log.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-ls-files.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-ls-remote.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-ls-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-mailinfo.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-mailsplit.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-base.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-file.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-index.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-ours.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-recursive.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-subtree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-merge.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-mktag.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-mktree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-mv.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-name-rev.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-notes.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-pack-objects.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-pack-redundant.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-pack-refs.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-patch-id.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-peek-remote.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-prune-packed.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-prune.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-push.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-read-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-receive-pack.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-reflog.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-remote-ext.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-remote-fd.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-remote.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-replace.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-repo-config.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-rerere.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-reset.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-rev-list.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-rev-parse.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-revert.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-rm.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-send-pack.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-shortlog.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-show-branch.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-show-ref.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-show.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-stage.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-status.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-stripspace.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-symbolic-ref.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-tag.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-tar-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-unpack-file.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-unpack-objects.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-update-index.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-update-ref.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-update-server-info.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-upload-archive.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-var.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-verify-pack.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-verify-tag.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-whatchanged.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git-write-tree.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
2011-04-04 09:39 <SYMLINK> git.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe]
106 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\ProgramData

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\ProgramData]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Desktop [C:\Users\Public\Desktop]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Documents [C:\Users\Public\Documents]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Favorites [C:\Users\Public\Favorites]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users

2009-07-14 06:08 <SYMLINKD> All Users [C:\ProgramData]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Default User [C:\Users\Default]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\All Users

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\ProgramData]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Desktop [C:\Users\Public\Desktop]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Documents [C:\Users\Public\Documents]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Favorites [C:\Users\Public\Favorites]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool

2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\Documents]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local

2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\Documents

2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\Music]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\Pictures]
2010-01-07 14:22 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\Classic .NET AppPool\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Default

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\Default\Documents]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Default\Documents

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\Default\Music]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\Default\Pictures]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\Default\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\dylan.beattie

2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\Documents]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Local

2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2010-01-07 12:51 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\dylan.beattie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Public\Documents

2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\Public\Music]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\Public\Pictures]
2009-07-14 06:08 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\Public\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Setup

2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\Setup\Documents]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Local

2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Local]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\Setup\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\Setup\Documents

2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\Setup\Music]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\Setup\Pictures]
2010-01-07 12:44 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\Setup\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.admin

2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Local]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\spot.admin\Documents]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Local

2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Local]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\spot.admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.admin\Documents

2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\spot.admin\Music]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\spot.admin\Pictures]
2010-05-05 11:47 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\spot.admin\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.daemon

2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Local]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users\spot.daemon\Documents]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Local

2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Local]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users\spot.daemon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\spot.daemon\Documents

2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users\spot.daemon\Music]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users\spot.daemon\Pictures]
2010-11-25 15:49 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users\spot.daemon\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006

2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Cookies [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Local Settings [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Local]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> My Documents [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\Documents]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> NetHood [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> PrintHood [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Recent [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> SendTo [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Start Menu [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Templates [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows emplates]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Local

2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Application Data [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Local]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> History [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> Temporary Internet Files [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows emporary Internet Files]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\Documents

2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> My Music [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\Music]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> My Pictures [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\Pictures]
2011-05-24 18:08 <JUNCTION> My Videos [C:\Users EMP.SPOTMAIN.006\Videos]
0 File(s) 0 bytes

Total Files Listed:
106 File(s) 0 bytes
127 Dir(s) 11,272,916,992 bytes free
```

So... I know the problem is caused by reparse points, I know where those reparse points are - what can I do about it? I've never worked with junctions/reparse points in NTFS before and since some of them look important (My Documents, various Git executables) I'm reluctant to start hacking around. Is there some way I can identify WHICH of those points is causing Windows Backup to fail, or some slightly more helpful tool I can use to explore and manage those reparse points?

Thanks,

Dylan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### What Microsoft says

If you read the [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455) article you linked more closely, you will see that error `0x81000037` apparently

> "occurs if the reparse point is a **mounted volume** that contains compressed files (for example, multimedia files, .zip files, and so on)"

(emphasis mine)

In the section *Workaround* of the same document, they emphasize that you should

> confirm the folder **Type** is **Mounted Volume**.

At the end they say

> By design, Windows Backup does not traverse reparse points on a computer. However, if a reparse point is directly added to a Windows 7 Library, or **if any of the child nodes of a reparse point is directly added to a Windows 7 Library**, Windows Backup traverses these locations. This could cause several issues during the backup process.

### My analysis

Reformulating what Microsoft says, out of *all* the reparse points you have *only the ones* which are "mounted volumes" are a problem (and then only if they contain "compressed files" and are included in a Win7 Library).

Looking at your list of reparse points, *none of them* seem to be mounted volumes (rather normal junctions and symlinks; see below for details), so I dare guess that *your reparse points are not the real source to your problem!!*

In my case I got the same **error message `0x81000037`** but it was **actually caused by Sophos Anti-Virus** refusing access to a file in the Shadow Copy. Putting an exception for that file (a harmless `autorun.inf` which I checked by hand) into the Antivirus configuration solved the problem without removing any junctions (like you, I didn't have mounted volumes).

### My answer

Apart from removing actual mounted volumes (see below), make sure nothing else interferes with reading the Shadow Copy. Using the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) as suggested by Duncan sounds like a good idea for that.

Don't remove innocent junctions, that won't help. In fact, you can replace Mounted Volumes by Junctions to make Windows Backup work :-).

### More Details about Mounted Volumes

Using [Hard Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) you can create "Mounted Volume" links, e.g. of your CD drive, and "Junctions". This is the HardLinkShellExt context menu I get when dragging my CD drive into a folder with the right mouse button:

[image]

For tests I created both a junction and a mounted volume. See what it looks like using `DIR /AL`, Windows Explorer and the folders' "Properties" tabs:

[image]

Comparing to [Microsoft's screenshot](http://support.microsoft.com/Library/Images/2526392.png) from the [above KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455), we learn that  `DIR` calls both junctions and mounted volumes `<JUNCTION>`; Windows Explorer differentiates them by using a folder or drive icon, but to be sure you can open the properties tab. Looking back to the output if `DIR`, the mounted volume is a reference starting with `\??\Volume`, which you don't have in your question; that is why I don't think that MSKB article applies to you.

### Replacing Mounted Volumes by Junctions

For people who *do* use Mounted Volumes and include them in a library (unlike to OP), *consider replacing them with junctions*; I did a test and this solved the problem:

- with mounted volume

[image: with mounted volume in library, no backup possible]

- with junction

[image: with junction, backup works]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for `0x81000037` was that i had my external USB drive formatted as **FAT32** and always after i hit a file with more than 4GB the backup failed with this error. After reformatting the drive to **NTFS** the backup completed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Usually in these scenarios I run [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), run the program and then search for Access Denieds etc in the resulting output.