# Does Windows 7 Backup save hidden files?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I have a lot of hidden directories in my Windows home and documents directories. I want them to be backed up and I am using the Windows 7 built-in backup mechanism.

**Will Windows Backup (the built-in one) also backup and restore hidden files/folders?**

(The system image doesn't count. That will probably include the hidden files, but I wonder whether the normal, shadow-copy based backups include hidden files.)

Bonus question: How does Windows Backup handle NTFS reparse points (aka symlinks)? If hidden files are not backed up, could I create non-hidden symlinks to hidden files/directories to get them backed up as well?

Comment: Windows Back up + reparse points? Thumbscrews would be more pleasant: http://superuser.com/questions/298019/what-can-i-do-about-windows-7-backup-error-0x81000037-apparently-caused-by-repa

Comment: @DarthAndroid Yeah, I know about the library "bug". Windows has been complaining about not being able to backup one of my libraries since forever. Why they wouldn't test **backup together with libraries** is a mystery to me. Maybe Windows 8 Backup will be better. Maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just verified it: **Windows Backup does indeed also backup hidden folders and it's contents**.

I took a backup created on schedule this morning and looked for a hidden folder I had specially created for testing this.

And indeed, I was able to restore a file in the hidden folder back to the state that was saved this morning.